# Creating a query that shows parameters as columns - BigQuery

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I'm using Firebase and BigQuery.
What I trying to do is create query which shows me average amount of "Orders", and "SoftCurrency" for each "Level", but I have no clue how to do it.

That is simplified JSON file of example event in my database. Such events are sent each time a player reaches the next level.

```
[
  {
    "event_name": "LevelUp",
    "event_params": [
      {
        "key": "Level",
        "value": {
          "string_value": null,
          "int_value": "12"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "SoftCurrrency",
        "value": {
          "string_value": null,
          "int_value": "623"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Orders",
        "value": {
          "string_value": null,
          "int_value": "24"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You will have to get all your data and do the query/filtering by code

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i did it:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(Level) as Lvl, FLOOR(AVG(SoftCurrency)) as average_Coins, FLOOR(AVG(Orders)) as average_Orders
FROM  (
  SELECT MAX(if(param.key = "SoftCurrency", param.value.int_value, NULL)) AS SoftCurrency,
    MAX(if(param.key = "Level", param.value.int_value, NULL)) AS Level,
    MAX(if(param.key = "Orders", param.value.int_value, NULL)) AS Orders
  FROM (
    SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, param
    FROM `analytics`,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS param
    WHERE event_name = "LevelUp"
    AND (param.key = "SoftCurrency" OR param.key = "Level" OR param.key = "Orders")
  )
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp
) 
GROUP BY Level
ORDER BY Lvl
```